# how to inject our services into angular unit test cases?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

This is what i am doing including total app using `beforeEach(module('myApp'));` according to my knowledge it has to load all the modules (like controllers, services etc..) and by writing below code i should be able to inject  service `preloadedData` but some have i get exception `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: preloadedDataProvider <- preloadedData`

`beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $httpBackend, $rootScope, $window, $location, preloadedData) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    location = $location;
    routeParams = $routeParams;
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    myController= $controller('myController', {
        $scope: scope,
        $location: location,
        preloadedData: preloadedData
    });
  }));`

could anyone help me on this..!!?

Comment: Your karma config file probably doesn't include the necessary JS file. Or you don't have any service named `preloadedData`.

Comment: My bad... you are right.. its not a service its a data generated by promises.. thanq very much... @JB Nizet

Comment: Hey @JB Nizet is there a way to include jQuery object into angular test cases